# Bootstrap theme/skin for TinyMce editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, tinymce

I want to give Bootstrap look and feel for TinyMCE editor which I am using in my MVC ASP.NET project. I know there is a way to create separate theme and also separate skin in TinyMCE documentation.

So I created a separate theme and now wanted to customize skin with Bootstrap CSS classes and icons.

Does anyone already implemented this kind of skin for TinyMCE? If so can you please share the skin files of TinyMCE with Bootstrap look and feel.

Or please pool in your suggestions.

Comment: This seems to be what you're looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/300193/tinymce-skin-or-theme-that-caresses-the-eyeballs-like-a-milk-to-a-goat